# Python ModuleNotFoundError: I can't import my module

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have got a CRUD App, I'm learning API rest with Python and Django... I create this module:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import serializers
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model: User
    fields = ['url', 'username', 'email', 'groups']
```

And after that, I write this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import viewsets
from djangoCRUD.Api.serializer import UserSerializer


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
"""
API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
"""

   queryset = User.objects.all().orderby('-date_joined')
   serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

This is all right, but, when I write my url.py Here, I have got a problem:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from rest_framework import routers
from djangoCRUD.Api import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('', include(router.urls)),
   path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

And I have this error message:

> File "C:\PythonDev\pythoncrud\venv\djangoCRUD\djangoCRUD\urls.py", line 20, in 
>       from djangoCRUD.Api import views
>       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'djangoCRUD.Api'

Comment: How about from Api import views, same result?

Comment: What is the name of your project and all the apps?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from rest_framework import routers
# from djangoCRUD.Api import views
from djangoCRUD.Api.views import UserViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
# router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('', include(router.urls)),
   path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```